# Mysql, combining and querying results with sub queries or temp tables

Tags: mysql, subquery, temp-tables

I am running into some trouble with the following circumstances: 
I have a query that creates two temp tables, and the following select to join them together--

```
    SELECT * FROM result 
    INNER JOIN result2 ON result2.packetDetailsId = result.packetDetailsId
```

I am then trying to create another column from concatenating a few of the resulting fields and then use that to reference/query against another table. Is there a way to accomplish this in one query? Should I get away from the temp tables?

Thank you again in advance.

---

update: If I try to alias the combination of the two temp tables I get an error message stating [Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'packetDetailsId'

```
    select * from (
    SELECT * FROM result 
    INNER JOIN result2 ON result2.packetDetailsId = result.packetDetailsId) as myalias
```

---

Another Update: I almost have it working as one query but I get the result "(BLOB)" in the column I concoctenated:

```
       select packet_details.packetDetailsId,products.productId,Credit,AccountNum,OrderStat,          CONCAT(products.productId,Credit,'_',OrderStat) as consol from (
    select packetDetailsId, GROUP_CONCAT(Credit) AS Credit, GROUP_CONCAT(AccountNum) AS AccountNum, GROUP_CONCAT(OrderStat) AS OrderStat FROM
 ( SELECT pd_extrafields.packetDetailsId,
CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Credit%') 
THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as Credit,
CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Account%') 
THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as AccountNum,
CASE WHEN pd_extrafields.ex_title LIKE ('%Existing%') 
THEN pd_extrafields.ex_value ELSE NULL END as OrderStat
FROM pd_extrafields  )AS TempTab GROUP BY packetDetailsId ) as alias2

    INNER JOIN packet_details ON alias2.packetDetailsId = packet_details.packetDetailsId
```

INNER JOIN sales ON packet_details.packetDetailsId = sales.packetDetailsId

INNER JOIN sold_products ON sales.saleId = sold_products.saleId
INNER JOIN products ON sold_products.productId = products.productId

Comment: You could probably do it in a single query, but what is your concern with using temp tables?  This can often make a complicated query easier to understand, and even run more efficiently since its easier for the engine to understand and create a better execution plan for as well.

Comment: Where are you concatenating the fields? In the join query of temp tables?

Comment: Yes Michael using the temp tables is making life easier. Ravindra, I'm actually combining two queries (one of which you helped with the other day) and then another query pulling in other relevant information. When I combine those two temp tables, it is from that resulting table from which I want to concatenate the fields. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have the temporary tables created and you need to "concatenate" the results, using `from ...  inner join ...`

The only possible restriction you may have is that you can only reference your temporary tables *once* in your `from` clause; besides that, there are no other restrictions (I frequently use temporary tables as intermediate steps in the creation of my final result).

---

### Tips

Let's say your temp tables are `temp_result1` and `temp_result2`. Both tables have a field `packedDetailsId`, on which the join will be performed. Remember to create the appropriate indexes on each table; at the very least you need to index `packedDetailsId` on both tables:

```
alter table temp_result1
    add index PDI(packedDetailsId);
alter table temp_result2
    add index PDI(packedDetailsId);
```

Now, just execute a query with the desired join and concatenation. If `concat` returns `BLOB`, then cast the result as `char` (of course, I'm assuming you need a text string):

```
select r1.*, r2.*, cast(concat(r1.field1, ',', r2.field2) as char) as data_concat
from temp_result1 as r1
    inner join temp_result2 as r2 on r1.packedDetailsId = r2.packedDetailsId;
```

I see your problem is that `GROUP_CONCAT` is returning `BLOB` values... It's normal (MySQL doesn't know *a priori* how to return the values, so it returns binary data); just use the `cast` function.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you Barranka, I'm actually trying to concatenate the results from the resulting table of the two temp tables.

Comment: @alex then you shouldn't have any problem... That's what temp tables are for

Comment: Barranka, any tips on how to do that successfully?

Comment: Barranka, I'm excited to try this out, and yes I was going crazy with the BLOB results, thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Barranka, thank you again, the cast() helped with the BLOB results, much appreciated, take care

Comment: @alex One last comment: even if MySQL returns a `BLOB`, the result is exactly what you need: The value *is* a string, but Workbench can't show it in the results grid; just right-click the result and select 'Show in viewer'

Answer (score 0):

so, if the result2 and result are both temp tables, you will have to include the # if local temp table and ## if global temp table

so your statements should be :

```
SELECT * FROM #result 
INNER JOIN #result2 ON #result2.packetDetailsId = #result.packetDetailsId
```

My Bad. This is only applicable for MS SQL